# Возврат значения из колбека c#

Tags: c#, события, task

Есть у меня некоторый метод:

```
public async Task<ProcessingCallback> ExecuteAction(Task<ApiProcess> process, ActionPreset actionPreset)
    {
        ProcessingCallback processingCallback = null; 
        process.Result.Execution += functionCallbak =>
        { 
            switch(functionCallbak.Result.FunctionMarker)
            {
                case EFunctions.create: { processingCallback = CreateVoucher(functionCallbak).Result.CallbackInit(actionPreset); }; break;
                case EFunctions.amout:  { processingCallback = AmountVoucher(functionCallbak).CallbackInit(actionPreset); }; break;
                case EFunctions.redeem: { processingCallback = RedeemVoucher(functionCallbak); }; break;
            }
        };
        await process.Result.AddActionAsync(actionPreset);
        return processingCallback;
    }
```

Его суть в следующем: Подписавшись на событие `Execution` внутри процесса мне оттуда приходит `funtioncallback`, который я обрабатываю в свитче и генерю другой тип колбека(`ProcessingCallback processingCallback`). Его же я и хочу вернуть в качестве возвратного типа, но приходит нулл. Судя по всему на обработку уходит больше временя и `return` сробатывает раньше чем кешируется `processingCallback`.  Каким образом мне реализовать мою задумку?

Comment: `TaskCompletionSource` должен помочь, если я правильно понял задачу.

Comment: Сколько раз у вас предполагается срабатывание события `process.Result.Execution`?

Comment: @ Pavel Mayorov каждый вызов `process.Result.AddActionAsync(actionPreset);` добавляет задачи в конвеер выполнения, результат которых приходит в `functioncallback`, получается, что постоянно.

Comment: а что так сложно всё? Смешались в кучу люди, кони.. зачем мешать в кучу [TAP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap) и [EAP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/event-based-asynchronous-pattern-eap)? И при этом, до кучи, видимо, вызывать `process.Result` напрямую. Вы сами себе вставляете круглые палки в квадратные колеса. Такой подход чем то мотивирован?

Comment: @ tym32167 скорее всего не полным пониманием вышеуказанных паттернов  и асинхронного программирования в частности.  Из поставленной перед собой задачей вытекает следуещее решение, создан некий апипроцесс в котором посредством метода `Execute` отправляются rest запросы и принимаются ответы, также есть событие сигнализирующее об этом и возвращающее в `functiocallback` те самые rest ответы. А как раз указанный в описании метод их обрабатывает. Под обрабатывает я имею ввиду сохранение части ответа в БД и дальше возврат ответа что все прошдо успешно.